# Android ListView Layout center

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

I want to make a prayer time app in android as shown below. I try to make it using a Listview and background image but can not achieve it.

[image]

Comment: where your activity.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

this is how you should go about it:
activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/your_image">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the parent set the background as your image, and populate listview with whatever data you like.

Comment: privide link to the background